# SQL SELECT for Cursor using an NVL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to modify the SELECT statement used in an employee interface file because it is returning an error when it passes an employee with their END_DATE is...well 'dated'.

I am pretty new to this, so in order to skip Oracle users that are end dated, I feel that using the NVL expression would be best here? However, after researching it, I am just not grasping the concept too well, and unsure if it is what I should be using.

Here is the statement:

```
FROM    oaa.xxap_employee_interim ei,
                hr.per_all_people_f ppf,
                hr.per_all_assignments_f paf,
                hr.per_addresses pa,
                apps.fnd_user u
        WHERE   new_update = 'U'
        AND     ppf.person_type_id = 6
        AND     ei.employee_number = ppf.employee_number
        AND     ppf.effective_end_date >= SYSDATE
        AND     ppf.person_id = paf.person_id
        AND     paf.effective_end_date >= SYSDATE
        AND     ppf.person_id = pa.person_id
        AND     u.employee_id = ppf.person_id
        --AND       NVL(u.end_date, SYSDATE + 5);
```

I was also suggested by a co-worker that using the 'IS NULL' would not be correct in this circumstance. Is that true? If so, why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No on can answer this because you have not explained what you mean.  I think you mean that there is no value in the u.end_date field.  If this is a case then I would expect `AND u.end_date is null` would be correct.  Why is it not correct?

Comment: So a user that has a value in the end_date column could mean that persons' access is to be cut off on that date.  Which could be 2 years from now. 2 years ago; or could be null meaning no end date defined. You said, "it is returning an error when it passes an employee with their END_DATE is...well 'dated'.".  So what is the error?  If it's a future date shouldn't it still be returned?  why would having a date cause the unknown error?  What happens if the person comes back and needs to be "undated?" if you can't select the record, how would the users edit it?  Too many unknowns to address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you want to check if u.end_date is a date in the past or is not null.   In that case I would use the following:

```
AND COALESCE(u.end_date, SYSDATE) < SYSDATE
```

The Oracle specific way to do that is

```
AND NVL(u.end_date, SYSDATE) < SYSDATE
```